# Expected number of iterations until all the cars can no longer move

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value

I am studying probability questions and I would like to revive [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3033154/expected-number-of-coin-flips-until-all-cars-move-to-end-of-array) for more attention.

Assume we have an array of length 2n. The first n slots are cars. Each round, we flip n coins where each coin $X_i$ corresponds to car i. $X_i$ is a fair coin and if it is heads, we will move car i to the right if the right space is free.

We are interested in the number of expected rounds until all the cars have moved to their final position at the end.

The previous question states that this is asymptotically O(nlogn) but I am unable to reason why. Thank you!

Comment: Are you interested in numerical results, or only in asymptotics? Also, do I understand correctly that the cars do not move simultaneously, even if possible by the coin flips?

Comment: I'm interested in both numerics and asymptotics, I just know that it is on the order of O(nlog n). I'm thinking about the problem where cars can move simultaneously (but i may be misinterpreting the problem)

Comment: I don't think the OP of the linked question really had a proof for the order O(n log n). Why exactly are you interested in this particular problem?

Comment: My friend asked me a similar problem and I wrote simulations out for it but i'm not sure how to actually prove it. I'm just curious. It's not for homework or anything like that

Answer (score 0):

For any finite $n$, you can calculate the expected number of moves exactly, by using a recursive formula. For example: say n$=3$ and let's identify a position with a string of 1's and zeros showing the position of the cars. Then the final position would be "000111". Since it requires zero moves until the 'end', we can say: f("000111")=0.

Then, for each position $p$, we can explicitly write down every transition from $p$, each having a chance $2^{-3}$ to occur. The expected number of moves until the end, starting from $p$, is then a weighted sum over $f$:
$$f(p)=\sum_{p'}2^{-3}\cdot (f(p')+1)$$, where $p'$ denotes positions which can occur after one transition from $p$ (and we count $p'$ just as many times as it can occur as result of a dice roll).

In this problem, the cars always move to the right, or don't move at all; so there will be no cycles in the recursive formula for $f(p)$ (except for $f(p)$ itself, which can be solved directly).

Because I saw two distinct interpretations of the question, I made an implementation for both. The first ("simultaneous") means that if two adjacent cars are to be moved together, only the rightmost car moves and the other doesn't. With the second ("one-by-one") I made the cars move starting from the rightmost car, so that collisions are avoided maximally.
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c||c} 
\text{cars} & \text{simultaneous} & \text{one-by-one} & \Delta \\ \hline
2 & 6.66 & 5.66 \\ \hline
3 & 12.08 & 10.08 &4.42 \\ \hline
4 & 17.82 & 14.82 &4.74 \\ \hline
5 & 23.76 & 19.76 &4.94\\ \hline
6 & 29.83 & 24.83 &5.07\\ \hline
7 & 37.98 & 29.98 &5.15\\ \hline
8 & 42.20 & 35.20 &5.22\\ \hline
9 & 48.47 & 40.47 &5.27\\ \hline
10 & 54.79 & 45.79&5.32 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
It is interesting to note that the expected value of the two different interpretations always differs by exactly the number of cars - 1. Perhaps this can be proven by hand.
Looking at the subsequent differences if the number of cars increases, I would believe $O(n\log n)$ to be true, although it is hard to rule out $O(n^2$).

Comment: This framework is very helpful, but I don't think that the transition probabilities are uniform. For example, in our starting position: 111000, we can end up in 110100 if we roll 001 or 101. It matters where the blocks occur. 

Also, in your definitions if we have 111000 and roll a 011, do we end up in 101100 or do we have 110100? I interpret a result of 101100 as the one-by-one result and the 110100 as the simultaneous result. Is that correct?

Comment: I think this is a problem of semantics: I saw the dice rolls as transitions, but of course different rolls can end up in the same position. There I double counted these positions in my sum for $f(p)$.
And yes, you interpret my two variations correctly.

Comment: I see - yes this framework is correct. Do you have a sense of what the analytical solution for this might be? I don't see a close formed solution of f(p)...