# Interesting expected value question about cars.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

My friend recently asked me a question that stumped me.

Suppose that we have $N$ cars parked occupying the first $N$ spaces of a line of length $2N$. Every minute, a car is considered eligible to move forward if the following conditions are met:

a) the space in front of them is empty, and
b) the number of the square they occupy is less than $2N$.

Suppose that every minute, if a car is eligible to move, then it has a $1/2$ chance of moving forward by one square. What is the expected amount of minutes before the cars occupy squares $N+1$ to $2N$?

I think there are interesting ways to exploit symmetry within the problem, and it seems like the expected time grows with $\mathcal{O}(N\log(N))$, but I'm having trouble arriving at a precise answer.

I wrote some code to do this. For $N=3$ you get $6850/567$. For $N=4$, you get $1445060858512/81048984345$. The numbers get out of hand pretty quickly after that.

Comment: For any particular $N,$ you can phrase it as a Markov process, but it will have $\binom{2N}{N}$ states, so it might take a lot. But it might be worth trying it for $N=3.$

Comment: I wrote some code to do this, for N=3 you get 6850/567, N=4 you get 1445060858512/81048984345, and the numbers get out of hand pretty quickly after that.

Comment: Show all your work in the question. I was about to start trying $N=3$ myself, and I might have ended up wasting a lot of time.

Comment: Have you looked up papers about TASEP (totally asymmetric simple exclusion process)? I'm not versed in the subject but perhaps there are existing results you can use.

Comment: Unless I made a mistake, the answer is $\frac{20}{3}$ for $N=2$. I can't find the sequence (of numerators, or of denominators) in the OEIS.

Comment: Already asked https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3033154/expected-number-of-coin-flips-until-all-cars-move-to-end-of-array

Comment: If I read Theorems 2.1 and 2.2 of https://people.math.wisc.edu/~tseppalainen/cornergrowth-book/ajo.pdf  correctly, the waiting time is almost surely $N \psi(1,1) = (2+2 \sqrt{2})N$ (take $p=q=1/2$ in Theorem 2.2). "Almost surely" means that, for fixed $\delta$, the probability of a waiting time more than $(2+2 \sqrt{2}+\delta)N$ or less than $(2+2 \sqrt{2}-\delta)N$ goes to $0$. This doesn't tell us what the expected time is though -- expected time can be dominated by large waiting times with very low probability. (Warning: I find probability literature hard to read.)