# Expected number of steps to move all cars to their new spots

Tags: probability, expected-value

There are N cars that are parked in N parking spots numbered from 1 to N. After the Nth parking spot, there are N more parking spots numbered from N+1 to 2N. At each step, a car is selected randomly and if the parking spot just ahead of it is empty, then it will move to the next parking spot with probability 1/2. What is the expected number of steps till all cars occupy the spots N+1 to 2N?

I tried using markov chains to solve this. Each state in the chain will be represented as (i,N-i), where i is the number of cars in the parking spots from 1 to N and n-i are the cars in the spots N+1 to 2N. State (0,N) will be the absorbing state. Using this I tried finding the expected number of steps to reach (0,N) from (N,0).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4744100/expected-time-to-occupy-space)

Comment: Thanks. I tried searching for this question but didn't find any.

Comment: Can you give me any advise on my approach?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/122293/expected-number-of-steps