# Maximum instances of compatible states with n eligible cars in car parking problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

This is a subproblem inspired by a problem described here: [Interesting expected value question about cars.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4733006/interesting-expected-value-question-about-cars)

Quoting the original problem, here is the setup:

Suppose that we have $N$ cars parked occupying the first $N$ spaces of a line of length $2N$. Every minute, a car is considered eligible to move forward if the following conditions are met:

a) the space in front of them is empty, and
b) the number of the square they occupy is less than $2N$.

Suppose that every minute, if a car is eligible to move, then it has a $1/2$ chance of moving forward by one square. What is the expected amount of minutes before the cars occupy squares $N+1$ to $2N$?

Analyzing the numerical results of code written to compute the exact values, I am conjecturing that the denominator can be written in the form
\begin{equation*}
  \displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^{n} (2^i - 1)^{2i(n-i) + 1}
\end{equation*}
while ensuring an integer numerator.
My attempt at interpreting this is that the exponent $2i(n-i) + 1$ represents the maximum possible number of states (distinct arrangements of cars) where there are $i$ eligible cars in any given run of the scenario (note that there are mutually exclusive states that cannot both occur in a single run). This follows from the observation that when there are $i$ eligible cars, the expected time to advance to a different state is $2^i / (2^i - 1)$. Are there any well-known results in combinatorics that explain this result or counterexamples to disprove it? I have verified it directly up to $n=3$.